# datagridview on Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I use Xamarin for an Android  project.

I want to create a table, with multiple columns and rows and editable cells.

I haven't found how to do this, because I need that table to be editable. I tried tablelayout and listview, but they are not what I am looking for. I just need an  idea.

Comment: Use `GridView`, I think that what you need.

Comment: Thank you, but using grid view, the table is not editable. I tried it.

Comment: What you do mean by editable? On-screen editable?

Comment: Yes, this is what I want.

Comment: You can use `GridView` and set `onClick` event for each and every `child-view` inside the item, also made them `selectable`. Every time you click on each `child-view`, display popup (or switch that `child-view`) with an `EditText` or `Spinner` or whatever fit with you data, change them, save, refresh `GridView`, that the BEST you CAN do. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! Please, post this comment as an answer, in order to be accepted.

Comment: Also, can I  do this using Table Layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GridView` and set `onClick` event for each and every `child-view1 inside the item, also made them`selectable`. Every time you click on each child-view, display popup (or switch that`child-view`) with an`EditText`or`Spinner`or whatever fit with you data, change them, save, refresh`GridView`, that the BEST you CAN do. Hope this helps.